# Regex between equal and ampersand

Tags: regex, url

I'm trying to find the string within a URL between `&client=` then the immediate `&` using regex

I thought about using it like this: `client=[a-zA-Z]+` but it stops at the _ so I really need it `&client=` to `&`

URL:

```
/search?q=tuition&btnG.x=0&btnG.y=0&site=transfer_credit&client=transfer_credit&proxystylesheet=transfer_credit&output=xml_no_dtd&proxycustom=HOME
```

The string after `site=` is always different and this should be unique enough to regex for it.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/lQ9hD0/2) is my attempt at the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your regex to:

```
client=.+?
```

Using your regex101 link:

https://regex101.com/r/lQ9hD0/6

Btw, you can use capturing group to capture the content:

```
client=(.+?)
```

Comment: @AJFarmar yes, i know, that works for alphanumeric. I'll update it for all the characters

Comment: I like what you had previously client=\w+ as its in between the &

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
client=[^&]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lQ9hD0/4)

This will match 1 or more of any character that is not `&`.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided any context for why you are trying to parse URL query string parameters with a regular expression, but in general it is not a good idea.

Here are the current answers and they all have problems:

```
client=[^&]+
client=.+?
client=(.*?)&
```

All of these answers will fail for one or more of the following reasons:

1. erroneously match other query parameter names that may contain the word `client` as a substring (e.g. `other_client`).
2. NOT match if the `client` parameter value is empty. Perhaps that's what you desire, but then you can't distinguish between the `client` value being empty and the `client` parameter being missing altogether.
3. requires an ampersand character after the `client` value. Therefore, it wouldn't recognize valid query strings where `client` was the last query parameter specified. The order of query parameters encoded in the query string is not guaranteed to be consistent. It could be the first parameter, last parameter, or any place in-between.
4. assumes the ampersand character `&` is the only character that can be used in query strings to separate query parameters. The semi-colon character `;` can be used instead.

What these answers demonstrate nicely is that parsing URL query strings with a regular expression is fraught with peril. It is difficult to account for all the valid variations that query string parameters and their values can assume.

If you must use a regular expression, here's one that I *think* will work for this specific case. Perhaps it too contains a bug I am not aware of?

```
\bclient=[^&;]*
```

But if you have the choice, it is better to use a library (in your language of choice) to parse the URL into its component parts.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
client=(.*?)&
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lQ9hD0/7).

I am using lazy quantificator `*?` to match as few characters is possible before a `&` sign. To get the value, you can put it into a capturing group: `client=(.*?)&` and get rid of a look-ahead (which is sort of "expansive"). Here is an example of how it can be coded in JavaScript:

```js
var re = /client=(.*?)&/; 
var str = '/search?q=tuition&btnG.x=0&btnG.y=0&site=transfer_credit&client=transfer_credit&proxystylesheet=transfer_credit&output=xml_no_dtd&proxycustom=HOME';
 
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = m[1]
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: Since you use a capture group to catch the result, there is no need to use a lookahead, use a simple character.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Thanks, a very valuable hint. I came up with a bit different approach, but it was "taken" before I hit ENTER :) :(